# 'flutter pub get' does not work in VSCode

Tags: flutter

I'm currently developing flutter application with VSCode and want to add some packages. ex) dropdown_menu

I did **flutter pub get / flutter packages get / clicking down arrow button in vscode(get Packages)**
and this is all I get everytime

```
PS D:\VSCodeProjects\testt> flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in testt...                               0.4s
PS D:\VSCodeProjects\testt>
```

this is my code in pubspec.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  dropdown_menu: ^1.1.0
```

I did turn on / off program( and computer)  , restart,

and

flutter clean

flutter packages get

flutter packages upgrade

Does anybody know how to solve??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's running, by default in vs code whenever you save your .yaml file it runs it under the hood. When you explicitly run it using the command, it takes very less time as the packages are already up to date.

If in doubt, try to use the new packages that you added and they should not give errors.

Comment: I used packages like import '~~' but it gives red line errors and also packages does not show in pubspec.lock file

Comment: Do not use vscode then, go to terminal in the project directory and run the command

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the **View > Command Palette** menubar option
2. Type "flutter"
3. Click "flutter get packages"

Answer (score 0):

flutter pub get is meant to be quick especially when you don't have much libraries.
What you see is right there should not be any problem.

But if there is issues where you are going for a specific version and it is not working, this is because pubspec.yaml stores the settings of what version of library but pubspec.lock stores the actual version your app is using.

Judging from your comments of it not showing up. It might be related to this [#31115](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31115#issuecomment-623313691)

try the solution and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in vscode

[Pubspec Assist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist)

Answer (score -2):

After typing the package don't forget to save the yaml file or click ctrl + s.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome. No offense, but this is really not a good answer. It's barely a comment. You don't need to tell programmers to remember to save files after editing them, the same way you don't need to remind them that their computer should be plugged in, in order to use it. ;)